# How can I automatically number the survey questions in my InDesign document?

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout

I'm relatively new to InDesign and I just know that I'm going about this project in a less than ideal fashion. I've done a lot of Google searching about numbering, but I seem to know little enough about InDesign that I can't quite phrase my search right.

Part of the reason I'm having trouble finding an answer is due to the way I want my document to be laid out. The simplest way to demonstrate this is with a picture:

[image]

You can see here that I have a 3p0 offset for most of the body text of the survey from the edge of the text frame. A blue margin separator (currently obscured by a guide; sorry) is put in at 1p6 inside the text frame. The text frame itself is 1p6 offset from the document margin which is 1p6 offset from the page edge.

I want my question numbers to appear just as they do here - between the document margin and the text frame - but I want the numbering to be automatic, and I want the numbers to follow along with the question text. Currently I am positioning and numbering manually.

I generally understand auto numbering (that's what I'm using for the page numbers) and paragraph/table styles, but I'm still unable to figure this out. How can I achieve this effect in a more manageable way?

Answer (score 3):

Set up a **Paragraph style** with numbering, via the **Paragraph Panel menu** by choosing **Bullets and Numbering...**.

[image: bullets]

You can configure the spacing and alignment associated with the numbering. Then adjust the text for other style options (font, size, spacing, etc) **Save the text as a paragraph style** and each new application of the style will result in an auto-number continuing from the last number used.

You can even configure a **Character Style** to apply to only the numbers in the Bullets and Numbering options dialog.

This needs to be in a single text frame to really work well.

Comment: That is an *awfully* scary item Seven, Scott.

Comment: Hey.. remember.. 7 ate 9.....

Comment: Thanks! This works really well so far, but there's one thing I can't figure out: when a question is long enough that it wraps to the next line, I can't seem to figure out how to get the second+ lines to have a hanging indent.